# Accelerating Java SecureRandom in a web environment

Tags: java, performance, cryptography

I'm developing what might become a pretty intense web application, which requires a large set of random numbers for cookie values, salt values, shared session identifiers and other similar sized (~ 20 bytes) items. The random numbers are typically required in response to user activity (such as registration, login, payment, etc.) Since the time of such activity is unpredictable, my premise is to try and use it to add entropy to the java.security.SecureRandom object in order to speed it up.

I have developed a class that uses the last 8 bits of the current system time of every 10th call to the random number generator to add entropy to the random number generator. My question is: Will this strategy deliver higher performance than just using SecureRandom with default seeding.

Please see the code below to see exactly how I'm doing this. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
/**
 * Uses the lowest 8 bits of the time at which the call to get random bytes 
 * is made to seed a  SecureRandom object to generate more randomness.
 * This class can speed up the random number generator if: Each call to 
 * nextBytes is of a limited length;
 * and the time at which nextBytes is called is unpredictable because it
 * is being done in response to user activity.
 * 
 */
public class SRandFactory {

private static final int BITLEN = 8;
private static final int BITMASK = 0xFF;
private static final int LONGLEN = 64;
private static final int INTERVAL = 10;

private static SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

private static long nextSeed = 0L;
private static int callCount = 0;
private static int shiftBits = 0; 

private static void seedUp() {
    if (callCount++ >= INTERVAL) {
        callCount = 0;
        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis() & BITMASK;
        nextSeed = nextSeed | (curTime << shiftBits);
        shiftBits += BITLEN;
        if ( shiftBits >= LONGLEN) {
            sr.setSeed(nextSeed);
            nextSeed = 0;
            shiftBits = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static synchronized void nextBytes(byte[] array) {
    seedUp();
    sr.nextBytes(array);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? This should be fairly easy to benchmark.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about benchmarking it, but I won't be able to get real entropy until it is in a live environment, and my system is currently under development. Also, this code will be running in a cloud server farm that isn't accessible to me right now (so I don't know how slow SecureRandom is going to be in real life either).

Comment: The SHA1PRNG implementation only uses system entropy for seeding the generator when constructing a new SecureRandom. After that, it doesn't touch system random sources.

Comment: @ntoskrnl - That would be a little bit of a security issue. I was going by this statement in the documentation: "Note: Depending on the implementation, the generateSeed and nextBytes methods may block as entropy is being gathered, for example, if they need to read from /dev/random on various unix-like operating systems." Are there other SecureRandom implementations that produce better randomness?

Comment: A proper PRNG can generate terabytes of cryptographically secure random numbers from 160 bits of entropy. Unfortunately I can't quote a source on this one; maybe someone else knows more?